# Ввести порт для подключения к серверу с "клавиатуры"...

Tags: winsock, c++

Добрый вечер!

Возникла очередная глупая проблема, которую я никак не могу решить... В сети куча примеров с вводом порта сервера типа такого: servAddr.sin_port=htons(12345);
А как запихать туда порт введенный с клавиатуры? Как сделать такое:

```
char a="12345";
servAddr.sin_port=htons(a);
```

Comment: Это вопрос, как преобразовать char[] в short int? atoi не подойдёт? (Кстати, `char a="12345";` -- ошибка. Или `char *a`, или `char a[]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только порт - очень просто

```
....
int port;

cin >> port;
servAddr.sin_port=htons(port);
....
```

А вообще я пользуюсь такой функцией

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

// returns 1 OK, 0 ERR
int
make_ipaddr (char *host, int port, struct sockaddr_in *a)
{
  struct hostent     *phe;

  a->sin_family = AF_INET;
  a->sin_port = htons(port);
  a->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  if (host && host[0]) {
    if (phe = gethostbyname(host))
      memcpy (&a->sin_addr, phe->h_addr, phe->h_length);
    else 
      if ((a->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host)) == INADDR_NONE) 
         return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Здесь `host` может быть как именем (типа www.mail.ru или localhost), так и IP адресом (типа 127.0.0.1). Как прочесть строку с клавиатуры, думаю понятно.

Вызов, например, так

```
....
// запуск потоков данных клиента
pid_t
runtcli (int n, char *host, int port)
{
  pid_t p = fork();
  if (p)
    return p;

  struct sockaddr_in sadr;

  if (!make_ipaddr(host,port,&sadr))
    fatal("Cli make addr");
  ....
```

(И когда же в конце концов, этот "редактор" будет правильно воспринимать табуляции при копи-пасте?)

Comment: Спасибо. Дабы не засорять форум глупыми вопросами, спрошу У вас... Есть SOCKET usersList[maxusernum]; Как из него в сервере вытащить ip клиента и преобразовать его в char?

Comment: Насколько понимаю в usersList[] открытые дескрипторы TCP. Тогда можно написать

    char *
    getchars_sock_addr (int sockfd)
    {
      struct sockaddr addr;
      socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    
      if (getpeername(sockfd, &addr, &addrlen))
        return 0; // errno is set
      return inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)(&addr))->sin_addr);
    }

Только учтите, что возвращается адрес на статический буфер в inet_ntoa() и данные в нем будут перетерты другим вызовом inet\_ntoa().

Соответственно, либо второй аргумент и копировать туда, либо return strdup(inet\_ntoa(...));

Comment: Места в комменте, как всегда мало.

Вызывайте, например
 
    char *ipstr = getchars_sock_addr(usersList[i]);
    cout << "Client IP: " << ipstr ? ipstr : strerror(errno) << '\n';

если сделали return(strdup(... , то дальше

    free(ipstr); // в линуксе можно не проверять на NULL

Да, инклюды для getchars\_sock\_addr()

    #include <arpa/inet.h>

и для strdup()

    #include <string.h>

Кстати, только сейчас заметил метку winsock. Примеры-то из \*nix, но надеюсь в винде тоже будут работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c[6];

    cin >> c;

    .... = htons(с);

    return 0;
}
```

наверно так

Comment: Нет, не так...( error C2664: 'htons' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [10]' to 'u_short'

Comment: тогда

char c[6];


 замените на

u_short c;